# Need to scrollbar overlap with data in css

Tags: html, css

I have one table data. there thead is fixed. I have added scroll only for tbody

```
tbody{
display: block;
    height: 102px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

SO here, thead and tbody is mismatching in alignment because of scrollbar.
Scrollbar takes some widtin tbody

https://jsfiddle.net/MohaideenIsmail/6hm2oaLe/

It is giving like this. how to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: can u create a fiddle

Comment: i think padding from right (17px) on last thead cell should do the trick, or not?

Comment: Add your code or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Mohaideen, it might be helpful : [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/crspu/555/)

Comment: I think, padding from right should be enought, something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5dv99tde/1/)?

Comment: added jsfiddle link in quesr

Comment: @RohitGoyani, i need to do it on css. because it is a angularjs table. i dont want use jquery

Comment: Added jsfiddle @gayathri

Comment: can u tell exactly whats the problem couldn't understand @Mohaideen

Comment: th border and td border are not in same. @gayathri

Answer (score 0):

Hi just replace the style

CSS

```
table {
    /* width: 100%; */ /* Optional */
    /* border-collapse: collapse; */
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]

table tbody,
table thead { display: block; }

thead tr th { 
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* text-align: left; */
}
table > thead > tr > th:not(first-child){
                min-width:145px;
            }
            table > tbody > tr > td:not(first-child) {
                min-width:145px;
            }

table tbody {
    height: 60px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

tbody { border-top: 2px solid black; }

tbody td, thead th {   
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

tbody td:last-child, thead th:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Check on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MohaideenIsmail/6hm2oaLe/)

Answer (score 0):

Well try this below code, I have added width to your th and td which align them perfectly, but on mobile device you have to use media queries and reduce the width of th, as below.

```
table > thead > tr > th{
  width:9.15%;
  text-align:left;
}   
tbody > tr > td{
  width:5%;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Align your text according as you want them to be.